# erro com MySQLi - não cadastrando no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estou migrando do MySQL para o MySQLi e têm alguns erros nesse meu script que não estão inserindo no SQL

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'controleestoque';

// conexão e seleção do banco de dados
$con = mysqlI_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// GET ID
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = '$idUsuario'";
    $qr = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);

    $nomeUsuario = $ln['nomeUsuario'];
    $celularUsuario = $ln['celularUsuario'];
    $emailUsuario = $ln['emailUsuario'];
    $dataBoleto = date("Y-m-d");
    $tipoPlano = "planoPrata";
    $valorBoleto = "120,00";


    /* Verifica se já tem um ID Boleto Repetido */
    while(true){

    $idBoleto = rand(1, 99999999999);
    $res = "SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE idBoleto = '$idBoleto'";
    $search = mysqli_query($con, $res);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($search) == 0){
    break;
    }
}

    /* Se não retornar com ID Boleto igual -> Continua */

    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO boleto (idBoleto, tipoPlano, valorBoleto, idUsuario, nomeUsuario, celularUsuario, emailUsuario, dataBoleto) values ('$idBoleto', '$tipoPlano', '$valorBoleto', '$idUsuario', '$nomeUsuario', '$celularUsuario', '$emailUsuario', '$dataBoleto')");

    header("Location:gerar_boletoPrata.php?id=$idBoleto");

 } /* Termina Isset Get ID */

 else {
     echo "
            <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index1.php' />
            <script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Você precisa estar logado para visualizar esta página!!')</script>
     ";
     }
// END
?>
```

Alguém poderia me dizer qual o meu erro?

Comment: a função da conexão "mysqlI_connect ()" deve ser mysqli_connect ()

Answer (score 0):

O certo é:

```
    <?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'controleestoque';

// conexão e seleção do banco de dados
$con = mysqlI_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// GET ID
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = '$idUsuario'";
    $qr = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);

    $nomeUsuario = $ln['nomeUsuario'];
    $celularUsuario = $ln['celularUsuario'];
    $emailUsuario = $ln['emailUsuario'];
    $dataBoleto = date("Y-m-d");
    $tipoPlano = "planoPrata";
    $valorBoleto = "120,00";


    /* Verifica se já tem um ID Boleto Repetido */
    while(true){

    $idBoleto = rand(1, 99999999999);
    $res = "SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE idBoleto = '$idBoleto'";
    $search = mysqli_query($con, $res);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($search) == 0){
    break;
    }
}

    /* Se não retornar com ID Boleto igual -> Continua */

    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO boleto (idBoleto, tipoPlano, valorBoleto, idUsuario, nomeUsuario, celularUsuario, emailUsuario, dataBoleto) values ('$idBoleto', '$tipoPlano', '$valorBoleto', '$idUsuario', '$nomeUsuario', '$celularUsuario', '$emailUsuario', '$dataBoleto')");

    header("Location:gerar_boletoPrata.php?id=$idBoleto");

 } /* Termina Isset Get ID */

 else {
     echo "
            <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index1.php' />
            <script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Você precisa estar logado para visualizar esta página!!')</script>
     ";
     }
// END
?>
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444574/same-script-php-on-localhost-doesn%C2%B4t-work-online